# Django Tastypie: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: django, tastypie

I am following the tutorial from django-tastypie, after Hooking Up The Resource(s), I went to `http://localhost:8000/api/entry/?format=json`, I got this error in JSON:

```
{"error_message": "maximum recursion depth exceeded", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_tastypie-0.9.14-py2.7.egg\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 202, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n\
```

models.py:

```
from tastypie.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # For automatic slug generation.
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)[:50]

        return super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

api.py:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from myapp.models import Entry


class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
```

Comment: Got some code you would like to share?

Comment: For example, you can post your model and resource ? It could help ;-)

Comment: I am following the tutorial from http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-resources

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570443/django-tastypie-throws-a-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-when-full-true-on-re

Answer (score 0):

try uncomment "(r'^blog/', include('myapp.urls')" which you put under urlpatterns and then run your application again.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the **"(r'^blog/', include('myapp.urls')"** which can be found under urlpatterns in your urls.py and then rerun your application.